# "Error code 51" when launching a game using Steam

Tags: steam

When launching a particular game - Rocket League in this case - I get "Game Launch Failed, error code 51". How can I fix this?

This is what it looks like:

[image: error code 51 when launching game from Steam]

I've seen a lot of 'solutions' around the net (often involving other games), but I can't find one that works in my case. I've tried reinstalling both Rocket League and Steam, but I keep getting the same problem. Other games seem to start just fine.

Comment: A quick Google search says the error is usually caused by old graphics drivers or third-party software (like an anti-virus).  Try the steps listed [here](https://appuals.com/fix-error-code-51-game-failed-to-start-on-steam/).

Comment: I have the same antivirus settings as friends (this is at work) and the game works fine for them. But I will have IT check to be sure. I'm partway through that list, and trying everything I've found in google searches. I've been at this for a few hours now. Will report if anything works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [most common causes](https://appuals.com/fix-error-code-51-game-failed-to-start-on-steam/) of this error are:

- Steam or the game have corrupted files.
  Since you reinstalled both, I presume this is not the cause in your particular situation;
- Applications like anti-virus software prevent the game from running;
- You graphics card drivers are out of date or corrupted;
- Missing Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable files.

The OP has already tried this first step, but I'll go over it for completeness' sake:

- - **Verify the integrity of the game files** of the game that gives you trouble.
    In your Steam library, right-click that game, and select `Properties`. Go to the tab `Local Files`, and click 'Verify Integrity of Game Files'.
  - **Verify the integrity of your Steam installation**.
    Note that this step is only really necessary if more than one game is giving you trouble.
    Navigate to your Steam folder (usually `C:/Program Files (x86)/Steam`), and delete all files *except the `Steam.exe` executable, and the `steamapps` and `userdata` folders*.
- In the OP's case, first try **disabling third-party applications** that are running in the background. Look for antivirus (e.g. AVG) and VPN software, firewalls, &c.
  [Here](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=9828-SFLZ-9289) is a more complete list of programs that can cause problems with Steam.
- If that doesn't help, **(re)install Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributables**.
  If these files are necessary for a certain game, they are provided by Steam. Navigate to the game folder (usually in `C:/Program Files (x86)/Steam/steamapps/common/`, the folder of the game, and a folder called `VCredist`). Execute the files you find there. You might also want to download and install the newest version of [DirectX](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/179113/how-to-install-the-latest-version-of-directx) if necessary (see link for steps to determine if this is necessary).
- If that didn't work either, **(re)install the newest video card drivers** ([Nvidia](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us) / [AMD](https://www.amd.com/en/support)) or, alternatively, **rollback to an older stable version** ([Nvidia](https://www.nvidia.com/object/driver_rollback.html) / [AMD](https://community.amd.com/thread/219804#comment-2821477) / or use [DDU](https://www.wagnardsoft.com/)).

Comment: This is the most complete answer I have found. In my case, it randomly started working, so I have no idea what the root cause was. I am accepting this one as it is a good reference for future people who have this problem.

Comment: And of course with a new C drive installed (Rocket League is on D) it's busted again. I suspect permissions somehow since I don't have admin.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this pop up again after getting a new C drive (the game was installed on D). My solution this time was:

- Log out of Steam.
- Log in as another user that I control.
- Request access to Rocket League.
- Grant access from the main account.
- Start Rocket League from the second account.
- Log out, log in with the original account
- Start Rocket League

I have no idea why this worked.